# Deploying a ListView on tabbar Issue

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

```
  host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Offers")
            .setIndicator("Offers",      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_light))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, List_Items.class)));
```

List_Items.class

```
 public class List_Items extends Activity{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       setContentView(R.layout.list_item);


  } //oncreate
```

list_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:background="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:textSize="22sp" 
android:text="Find Car"
android:enabled="false"  
>
</TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="5"></ListView>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1.2">
    <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/btn_sync"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
      </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.8">

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, now I want to change the  public class List_Items extends Activity to extends ListActivity because I don't see the the scrolling action on output. Once I changed to extends ListAcitivity the program crashed. what's the reason?

Comment: I can't see any output on my logcat of DDMS. but if I have extend Activity it's OK. extends ListActivity the program crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the android documentation:

"ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)"

You don't have an item with id "list" in your layout.

Comment: OK, I add the id but still failing, my ListActivity which deplay the list_item.xml consists more than just listview, it also has an button, an image on top and below the listview. is that OK?

Comment: my bad, it should @id/android:list, it's OK now

Answer (score 1):

You  need to have a list entry with id @andriod:id/list in your list-item.xml. My guess your logcat also showing same message.

Comment: OK, I add the Id to my listview in XML but program still crashed.

Comment: my bad, it should @id/android:list, it's OK now